# Why getting run-time error after updating to latest stable version of xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

- Updated ‘xamarin for visual studio’ and ‘xamarin studio’ both.
- Debugged our application after up-gradation, it has given some run time error on both the IDE (VS2015 and XS6.0).
- Getting an exception in run time “System.Argument.Exception : Set Method Not Found For ‘Element’ ”.
- It was running well before the up-gradation to cycle 7 .
- Attached an screen shot for your reference please have a look on it.
- And please provide some assistance otherwise it will be difficult to find the reasons behind the issue.

Thanks

Link for error message screenshot -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5TjG.png

Comment: Try to clean solution (also remove `bin` and `obj` folders) and run build again.

Comment: "attached is a screenshot" where is it?